# Is there any general, theoretical limit to time - space tradeoff?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, theory

In many algorithms, one can spot that improvements in time often are occupied by more memory requirements. For example usage of cache allows to speed up calculations by saving results in memory.

Is there any theoretical limit of "time-space tradeoff" similar to Amdahl's law limiting speed-up from the parallelization of calculations?

## Example

**Assumption**: we will neglect the size of the call stack.
To illustrate how time-space tradeoff works let us think about **Fibonacci sequence calculations**.
One can calculate Nth Fibonacci seq. element using the below equation:

```
fib(n) = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
fib(1) = fib(2) = 1
```

Notice, that to compute Nth element we need to calculate 2 previous ones. To calculate each of these we need to calculate 2 previous ones for each of them and so on...

Straightforward implementation be:

```
function fib(n) {
  if (n == 1 || n == 2)
    return 1;
  return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
}
```

Let's visualize this using graph for N=6:
[image]
Notice, that some calculations are repeated:
[image: Repeated elements]
What one can do to speed up algorithm is to remember results of repeated calculations and reuse them. **One is trading space for time**.

Implementation of such tradeoff:

```
const resultsCache = [1,1];
function fib(n) {
  if (resultsCache[n])
    return resultsCache[n];
  fibN = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
  resultsCache[n] = fibN;
  return fibN;
}
```

## Question

**Is there any theoretical limit of "time - space tradeoff" as presented in above example?** It is how much we can speed up algorithm by using more space?

Comment: You can cache the result of every operation you do twice or more times, however you have to do it at least *once*. That's the limit I can think of. Not sure if there is a theory about that. On the other side, memory is limited too, and managing memory gets more complicated with more data, so I think you reach the same limits as you do with parallel processing.

Comment: Oh, and "time - caching space" is one thing, but "time - space" is probably to complex to put into an universal law. Think of hashtables and others.

Comment: You might consider asking this on the [Computer Science SE](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Isn't the theoretical limit precomputing the results for every possible input and storing it in memory, resulting in a simple lookup?

Comment: There are theoretical limits, yes. For example, the best possible case for sorting is O(n) because you *must* look at every element at least once to ensure that it's in the proper place. No amount of memory will allow you to sort faster than O(n).